# Does SublimeLinter have a setting or plugin for more pronounced warnings?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimelinter

Right now [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/) only shows warnings in very small text in a really inconspicuous place.

[image]

Whereas Atom has these big, beautiful warnings:

[image]

I know Sublime has plugins and settings for everything under the sun so I was just wondering if there was a way to make the SublimeLinter errors more pronounced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you very briefly read through the documentation you linked to, you'll see that SublimeLinter shows errors in three ways: the message in the status bar that you are currently seeing, setting an icon in [the gutter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/gutter_themes.html), and [marking](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/mark_styles.html) the code itself. Instructions on setting the gutter theme and mark style are [here](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/gutter_themes.html#choosing-a-gutter-theme) and [here](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/mark_styles.html#choosing-a-mark-style), respectively. [Here](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/gutter_themes.html#standard-gutter-themes) are the standard gutter themes; you can also [create your own](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/gutter_themes.html#creating-a-gutter-theme).

Comment: My problem is that the text is annoyingly inconspicuous, not that I don't see the warnings. One of those things is designed better than the other one and I was just hoping SublimeLinter could mimic it.

Comment: @CorySimmons while ST3 does support popups now, SublimeLinter does not currently take advantage of this feature. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3/issues/178) for this, and [this comment](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3/issues/178#issuecomment-131400465) (and the reply a little farther down) tell you how to hack in a quick popup functionality. I can add this to the answer if you want.

Comment: Great news. Hopefully they'll implement. Thanks for expanding on your answer.